# Нужно ли вызывать Dispose для контекста Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Делаю проект просто с целью обучения, там создал класс CommentService, в котором содержатся методы для работы с БД (с целью сократить код в будущем):

```
public class CommentService : IDatabaseService<Comment>
{
    private readonly ILogger<CommentService> _logger;
    private readonly DatabaseContext _db;
    public CommentService(ILogger<CommentService> logger, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _db = context;
    }

    public async void AddEntity(Comment entity)
    {
        _db.Comments.Add(entity);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<Comment>> GetAllEntitiesAsync()
    {
        return await _db.Comments.ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<Comment>> GetAllCommentsByPostId(int postId)
    {
        return await _db.Comments.Where(p => p.PostId == postId).ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<Comment> GetEntityByIdAsync(int id)
    {
        return await _db.Comments.FindAsync(id);
    }

    public async void RemoveEntityById(int id)
    {
        _db.Comments.Remove(await GetEntityByIdAsync(id));
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _db.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем: будет ли правильным такой подход? Имею в виду передачу через конструктор контекста БД из другого класса сюда, а затем вызова Dispose? Или лучше в каждом методе использовать `using(DatabaseContext _db = new DatabaseContext())`?
Как я понимаю, и то, и другое подразумевает Dispose, и он нужен, чтобы можно было работать с контекстом в разных классах и чтобы не было конфликтов, но что более правильно и нужно ли вообще?

Comment: почитайте про паттерн `UnityOfWork`, и то что вы написали сервис, вы уже сделали шаг к изучению многослойной архитектуры...до кучи можно еще почитать про паттерн `Repository`. На [метаните](https://metanit.com/) был достаточный минимум описания всего, что я перечислил.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц благодарю! Похоже, это то, что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зависит от архитектуры вашего приложения.

В показанном вами варианте ваш CommentService **владеет** контекстом. Это означает следующее:

1. контекст не может быть общим для нескольких сервисов;
2. если вы используете DI - то вам надо регистрировать контекст как Transient.

В то же время, вы можете просто убрать вызов Dispose. В таком случае, ваш CommentService будет **заимствовать** контекст. Это будет означать следующее:

1. контекст смогут использовать несколько сервисов одновременно;
2. тому, кто управляет временем жизни контекста и сервиса, нужно будет следить чтобы контекст не "умер" раньше сервиса;
3. если вы используете DI - то вам надо регистрировать контекст как Scoped или Singleton.

Вариант с `using` тоже будет работать, только вам лучше использовать не конструктор, а что-нибудь вроде фабрики контекстов - иначе вы не сможете передать в контекст никаких зависимостей. Вместо фабрики контекстов можно использовать `IServiceScopeFactory`, но лучше так не делать, поскольку нетипизированная `IServiceScopeFactory` скрывает тот факт, что сервису нежен именно контекст, а не что-то ещё.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. То есть в моем случае, если я однажды передам в конструктор сервиса контекст, то в другие сервисы нельзя так же передать контекст или что? Не очень понимаю, до этого просто вообще сервисы не использовал и не до конца понимаю, что стоит делать, а что нет.

Comment: @TimofeyMelentev если ваш сервис делает Dispose контексту - то вы не можете тот же самый объект передавать в другие сервисы, иначе возможны ошибки.